# Compilation of the program - Bad intuitiion

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;
class cpte_obj
{  static int ctr ;             
 public :
   cpte_obj () ;
   ~cpte_obj () ;
} ;
int cpte_obj::ctr = 0 ;  
cpte_obj::cpte_obj ()           
{  cout << "++ construction : il y a maintenant   " << ++ctr << " objets\n" ;
}
cpte_obj::~cpte_obj ()          
{   cout << "-- destruction  : il reste maintenant " << --ctr << " objets\n" ;
}
int main()
{  void fct () ;
   cpte_obj a ;
   fct () ;
   cpte_obj b ;
   return 0;
}
void fct ()
{  cpte_obj u, v ;
}   


/* Results: 

    ++ construction : il y a maintenant   1 objets
    ++ construction : il y a maintenant   2 objets
    ++ construction : il y a maintenant   3 objets
    -- destruction  : il reste maintenant 2 objets
    -- destruction  : il reste maintenant 1 objets
    ++ construction : il y a maintenant   2 objets
    -- destruction  : il reste maintenant 1 objets
    -- destruction  : il reste maintenant 0 objets */
```

Here is a program that our teacher made available in the course notes. I need that explained to me the lines:

```
   -- destruction  : il reste maintenant 1 objets
   ++ construction : il y a maintenant   2 objets
   -- destruction  : il reste maintenant 1 objets
```

Why is the number of objects jumped to 2 and back to 1. The result of the number of objects it should not be 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0? Does someone could explain to me how the program compiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an object goes out of scope, the destructor is invoked.
Objects are destroyed in reverse order of their construction.

```
   ++ construction : il y a maintenant   1 objets- construction of object 'a'
        ++ construction : il y a maintenant   2 objets- construction of object 'u' in fct()
        ++ construction : il y a maintenant   3 objets- construction of object 'v' in fct()
        -- destruction  : il reste maintenant 2 objets- destruction of object 'v' in fct()
        -- destruction  : il reste maintenant 1 objets- destruction of object 'u' in fct()
        ++ construction : il y a maintenant   2 objets- construction of object 'b'
        -- destruction  : il reste maintenant 1 objets- destruction of object 'b'
        -- destruction  : il reste maintenant 0 objets- destruction of object 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

The object constructed between destructor calls is `b`.  It doesn't get constructed until after `u` and `v` are destroyed due to exiting `fct`.